# registerServiceWorker [ERROR] Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, service-worker, ecmascript-5

Well i used `register-service-worker`, so the `registerServiceWorker` boilerplate remained unchanged.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n'
      );
    },
    registered() {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.');
    },
    cached() {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.');
    },
    updatefound() {
      console.log('New content is downloading.');
    },
    updated() {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
    },
    offline() {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    },
  });
}
```

So tried `yarn build` for production. All green. But once i deploy/localhost this error appeared

`Cannot use import statement outside a module` in `service-worker.js`

As i pretty much figure alternative of adding `<type="module">` under script. But that's kinda not practical to do so in vue-project, any suggestion to fix such? Here's my config for pwa in `vue.config.js`

```js
// vue.config.js
pwa: {
    manifestOptions: {
      background_color: '#f2f2f2',
      purpose: 'maskable any',
    },
    // configure the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
      swSrc: 'src/registerServiceWorker.js',
      swDest: 'service-worker.js',
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... the problem is what the error message says: you're not allowed to use the `import` statement in your Service Worker script ('service-worker.js').

Maybe you confused `import` with `importScripts`? The latter is what you should use in Service Workers. Please add your service-worker.js into your question for more instructions =)

Comment: thanks for replying. I realised it worked along with new/empty service-worker in my public folder. But what would be general/best `service-worker.js` to work in InjectManifest?